# What is a typealias in Kotlin and how is it being used in this implementation?

Tags: kotlin

I see there is a typealias keyword being used and then the invoke method is being called on that "type"

Can someone please provide insight into what this is and how it is being used?

```
typealias NewKittiesReceived = (Kitty) -> Unit

class KittyRepository {
    private val timer = Timer()
    private val random = Random()
    private val period = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)

    internal fun receiveNewKitties(newKittiesReceived: NewKittiesReceived) {
        timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                val nameRandom = random.nextInt(KittyNames.values().size)
                val ageRandom = random.nextInt(5)

                newKittiesReceived.invoke(Kitty(KittyNames.values()[nameRandom].name, ageRandom))
            }
        }, period, period)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you confused about `typealias`, or about `(Kitty) -> Unit`?

Comment: I think both - And I am also confused about the use of the invoke method on newKittiesReceived. It seems weird because we are passing in a typealias object and then calling invoke on the instance of that object.

Comment: I'm wondering how invoke is typed to (Kitty) -> Unit

Comment: That is a function type (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types)

Comment: Okay - so we are defining a function type using a typealias keyword and then calling the "invoke" method on that function using the variable reference?

Comment: In Kotlin, lambda types have the format `Receiver.(Parameters) -> Return`. If your lambda does not have a receiver (with appears as `this` inside the lambda), you can omit it. The `typealias` is then an alias for the lambda type `(Kitty) -> Unit`. And as every other lambda type, you can call the `invoke` method on it - or even use the overloaded operator `()`

Comment: You need a dictionary, not a tech advice. What does the word “alias” mean to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s often more readable to have dedicated names for function types, such as `(Kitty) -> Unit`. In the end, a typealias simply gives us a way to define an alias for such a (e.g.) function type which can then be used throughout the code *instead* of that explicit type as a 1:1 replacement.

In your example the function type `(Kitty) -> Unit` is being aliased with `NewKittiesReceived`, which is an argument to the shown function `receiveNewKitties`. Every variable holding a function (`newKittiesReceived` in the example) can be invoked with `function.invoke(arguments...)` **or** simpler with `function(arguments)`.

There’s only a single situation in which the `typealias` is used actually: the definition of `newKittiesReceived: NewKittiesReceived` will be translated to `newKittiesReceived: (Kitty) -> Unit`.

The docs are found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html).

Comment: I do not see much of this coming form the world of Android. Thank you for helping me understand.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html) says:

> Type aliases provide alternative names for existing types. If the type
>   name is too long you can introduce a different shorter name and use
>   the new one instead.

So, as you can see, typealises improve readability and shorten names that are to long.